# React js component on router / header footer nav on switch

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hello in my directions file I set my struct header navbar and my switch footer

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path="/login" component={AuthPage} exact={true} /> 
          <Route path="/dashboard/addProduct" component={AddProduct} exact={true} /> 
   <div>
    <Header/>
    <Navigation/>
    <Container maxWidth="lg" >
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route path="/xd" component={AuthPage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
      </Container>
    </div>  
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

basically i have a router app
where I have my navbar footer header and my content

and my content would be with the switch
to just render my content

and it works fine, but I have routes where I don't want to render my navbar footer header
how would i get this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path` prop in `Route` accepts also an array of paths. You can always set these paths, where you want component to render. Just move your e.g. `Header` component to `Route` and specify where exactly you want it to appear.

```
<Route path={['/routeYouWantHeaderToRender', 'otherRoute']} component={Header} />
```

Comment: But by doing that I would still only be able to update my content / main?

Comment: <Route path={['/xd', '/']} component={Header} />  
I did it and my header just popped my header, I got a little confused on how to use it

Comment: @SpiritYang Remember to remove `<Header />` if u use Route

Comment: yeah i make this:       <Route path={['/', '/xd']} component={Header} /> 
      <Route path={['/', '/xd']} component={Navigation} />  but only my header render / my navigation no

Comment: @SpiritYang You have to move it outside Switch I believe

Comment: yes it really was that

   <Route path = {['/', '/ xd']} component = {Header} />
    <Route path = {['/', '/ xd']} component = {Navigation} />
    <Route path = "/ dashboard / addProduct" component = {AddProduct} exact = {true} />

but when I add a 3 route where I don't want it to be displayed my header and navigation still appears

Comment: @SpiritYang Could you try to add `exact` prop? `<Route path={['/', '/ xd']} exact component={Header} />`

Comment: omg thank you very much worked out

https://pastebin.com/CZJ9gtmn

about this I want only one section to render the main

example header nav main footer only main render

except some routes I don't have this structure

For this I need to put only the ones that will render in main inside the switch?

Comment: Or can I do it better?

Comment: @SpiritYang I think that big components (pages) like Login, AuthPage, LandingPage should be inside Switch since Switch will render the first Route that matches the path